# Android push notification : Multiple notifications displays same data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification, kotlin-android-extensions

I have an app which displays notifications generated from the backend, each and every notification contains different data and when clicked upon should display the appropriate content on the notification page.

For example: Say i get 3 notifications one has the data RED with id 1, then i get another which has BLUE with id 2 and another with data GREEN with id 3, so whenever i click on any notification say RED, BLUE or GREEN it always opens the notification page for RED

```
@Override    
public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        ctx = context;
        model = new Model();
        String subtitle = bundle.getString("subtitle");
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        String body = bundle.getString("body");
        String eventJsonString = bundle.getString("extraData");
        JSONObject extraObj = null;
        try {
            extraObj = new JSONObject(eventJsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String Id = null;
        try {
             deviceId = extraObj.getString("Id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if( Id == null){
            Log.d("Notification","ready notification "+bundle.get("Id"));
            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.setAction(ServiceConstants.NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(result);
        }
        else{
    isNotification = true;
            try {
                    model.setId(Integer.parseInt(extraObj.getString("Id")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        //Type is not available with notification bundle
        try {
                model.setType(extraObj.getString("Type"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.setType("NA");
        }

    }
    sendNotification(title, subtitle, body, context);

}

private void sendNotification(String title, String subtitle, String body, Context context) {

    Intent intent = null;
    if(isNotification){
        intent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("model", model);
    }
    else{
        intent = new Intent(ctx, MyActivity.class);
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            ctx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    String id = "com.example.testnotification";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setChannelId(id)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(subtitle +"\n" + body))
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setContentText(body);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    mNotificationManager.notify(random, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass unique id here

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx,id,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: thanks this works for me, just need to pass unique id